# Benchmarking comet applications

Tags: node.js, benchmarking, long-polling

I'm currenctly working on my master's thesis. It's about real-time webapplications.
Now I'd like to compare Node.js with for example long polling.

I know some benchmarking tools such as ab, autobench etc., but these don't really test the application. Once they've made a request to the server, the request is handled and a new request is made. What I need is a benchmarking tool that will 'stay' on the webpage for a longer time so it'll simulate real people.

For example: I've made a demo chat in both Node.js and long polling (PHP). Now I want to test this with 100 simultaneous that stay on the chat for about 30 seconds.

Does anyone has some suggestions for me how I can reach this goal?

I thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't compare a software stack (node.js) to a technology (long polling). That's totally silly! I think you do not have understand what node.js really is. And long polling implemented in PHP? Worst idea ever, PHP was not meant for this, all solutions are ugly hacks.

Comment: @TobiasP. I think you've misunderstood my goal. I perfectly know what Node.js is. My goal is to create e.g. a demo application with node.js and the same demo application with PHP (long polling or short polling). Then I would like to compare both and see what technology I'd like to use for my real project.

Also, if not with PHP, how should I implement long polling then?

Answer (score 0):

> Now I'd like to compare Node.js with for example long polling.

Long polling itself is a platform agnostic web push technology, so you can compare long polling application made in node.js with similar application made in PHP for example.

> What I need is a benchmarking tool that will 'stay' on the webpage for
>   a longer time so it'll simulate real people.

You can create another server application which would simulate client connections, however this application shouldn't be hosted on the same machine as your long poll server application in order to have "near real" latency between clients and server. Even this approach may not give you exact environment as you would have with "real human" clients (since server application simulating client connection would be on the same origin and also because of famous quote *"there is no test like production"*), but it can give you rough environment to test your long polling server to gather some benchmark data. For example socket.io has [this kind of application](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO-node-client) for simulation of a variety of browser transports.

Comment: I think I have found another solution: selenium RC (http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/). The only issue left is when I want to test this with 100 clients, selenium will open 100 browser sessions on the clientmachine. I need to find a way to a) run this in the background b) spread it across multiple machines.